# Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in process.php on line 45, theres a problem with "if(count($result)==1)"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, crud

```
<?php

session_start();

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'crud') or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); //Izveido savienojumu ar datubāzi

//default values
$id = 0;
$update = false;
$name = '';
$age = '';
$mobile = '';
$location = '';

if (isset($_POST['save'])){     //pārbauda vai ir nospiesta save poga
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];

    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO data (name, age, mobile, location) VALUES('$name', '$age', '$mobile', '$location')") or     //ievada datus datubāzē
        die($mysqli->error);

    $_SESSION['message'] = "Record has been saved!";    //iestata sesijas ziņojumu, ja dati tiek saglabāti
    $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "success";

    header('location: crud.php');       //novirza atpakaļ uz crud.php
}


if(isset($_GET['delete'])){     //pārbauda vai ir nospiesta delete poga
    $id = $_GET['delete'];
    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM data WHERE id=$id") or die($mysqli->error());       //izdzēš datus no datubāzes

    $_SESSION['message'] = "Record has been deleted!";      //iestata sesijas ziņojumu, ja dati tiek izdzēsti
    $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";

    header('location: crud.php');       //novirza atpakaļ uz crud.php
}

if(isset($_GET['edit'])){               //pārbauda vai ir nospiesta edit poga
    $id = $_GET['edit'];
    $update = true;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id=$id") or die($mysqli->error());   //izvēlās datus no datubāzēs
   if(count($result)==1){                  //ja atrod ierakstu datubāzē
        $row = $result->fetch_array();      //atgriež datus no ieraksta
        $name = $row['name'];
        $age = $row['age'];
        $mobile = $row['mobile'];
        $location = $row['location'];
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['update'])){        //pārbauda vai ir nospiesta update poga
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];

    $mysqli->query("UPDATE data SET name='$name', age='$age', mobile='$mobile', location='$location' WHERE id=$id") or      //atjauno vecos datus uz jaunajiem ievadītajiem datiem
        die($mysqli->error);

   $_SESSION['message'] = "Record has been updated!";       //iestata sesijas ziņojumu, ja dati tiek atjaunotie
   $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "warning";

   header('location: crud.php');    //novirza atpakaļ uz crud.php
}
?>
```

It's telling me that Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in process.php on line 45, theres a problem with "if(count($result)==1)", and I can't find the problem for some reason, probably cos i'm a beginner. Anyway this is a CRUD - Create, Read, Update, Delete - and the Update/Edit function is not working so I'm stuck

Comment: Use `$result->num_rows` instead of `count($result)`

Comment: `$result` is not an array, so you can't use `count()` on it. Please read the  [manuals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). You will find an example how to get the number of rows in the result.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query` won't return anything countable, but it's not necessary to count just to see if you have a result or not. Since you're selecting by id, you'll only be able to get a maximum of one row from the query, assuming id is unique.

So you can just check that the query executed successfully and then try to get a row from it.

```
if ($result && $row = $result->fetch_array()) { ...
```

If the query failed, `$result` will be `false`, and if it was successful but didn't return anything, then `$row` will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($result && $row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $age = $row['age'];
    $mobile = $row['mobile'];
    $location = $row['location'];
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Oh, my bad. The problem here is changes in structing of files due to new php version. The code asked in this post is actually correct on older php but newer one from 7.x  show it as a error of array being passed as a countable like in count($result) ==1 which is solved by fetching array as result->fetch_array